# How to prevent Firebase signInWithPhoneNumber to change auth state

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement firebase's `signInWithPhoneNumber` just to verify user's phone number without really registering which I can not bypass. But the problem is that it excecutes the `onAuthStateChanged` function which then logs the user out since it is not possible to link email with phone number accounts.

I also did read the documentation about linking the already registered(user with email) with phone but without success.

So my question is, is there any way I can detect which auth provider is in `onAuthStateChanged` just to return the function or is there possibility to link email with phone?

Any help is appreciated! If code needed just ask.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you should always add the relevant code.  But I'm not clear on what you mean by "detect which auth provider is in onAuthStateChanged just to return the function".  You can't change the behavior of `onAuthStateChanged` with respect to the call to `signInWithPhoneNumber`, but it's not clear to me what you're actually trying to accomplish

Comment: @DougStevenson I have user created with `createUserWIthEamilAndPassword` Now if user is logged in he/she has the ability to add phone number and I want to verify it. Since I know firebase's phone authentication sends the verification code needed I thought I would use it to verify user's phone number. As I see it is not possible to link email and phone number accounts. And the reason I did not add any code is that I have no errors but a question if it is possible to link phone number if user uses the `signInWithPhoneNumber` if he is already logged in,

Comment: Errors are not required to add code.  Code is always helpful to visualize what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth doesn't have a mechanism to just verify a phone number without also signing in - that's just not a supported use case.  You might want to look into other products that do phone number or SMS validation.  Firebase Auth is just for managing actual user accounts for the people using your app.

Comment: But is it possible to link them like you link oauth providers?

Comment: The documentation for phone auth suggests it is. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#next-steps

Comment: This documentation page at the end https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#next-steps leads to other page talking about linking auth provider credentials to an existing user account but it is not possible with phone auth. "User can only be linked to one identity for the given provider." if trying to link.. And the provider is `PhoneAuthProvider`

Comment: OK, so it sounds like it's not possible.

Comment: You should reach out to Firebase support with a feature request if something isn't working the way you'd like.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support